# Theme Style don't work on custom LiestView Items

Tags: android, listview, styles, themes

I want to build a theme for my app. But it seems like my LiestView item don't apply the values.

This is the styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextView</item>
</style>
    <style name="TextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:layout_margin">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#87000000</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>
```

in my activity i use a Listview with Custom Adapter but the TextViews from my item.xml did'nt have a margin:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="de.resper.enigma2chromecast.mainLive" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/channelName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:id="@+id/channelLine1"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do all the other attributes work in your list item?

Comment: I add a backgroundcolor and that works without problems, only the margin didn't work

Comment: It may because of layout parameters of your linear layout. It may be overriding your theme or it just can't be seen (8dp isn't that big). You may also be using the incorrect parameter i.e. "layout_margin", you may want to make it like margin left or margin right, or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

what ever you designed xml, put in android manifest file in application theme

`<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">`

Comment: I did that before. That is not the problem.